# ImportError: The 'enchant' C library was not found. Please install it via your OS package manager, or use a pre-built binary wheel from PyPI

Tags: python, import, file-not-found, win64, enchant

The question is why I see the error message in the title when trying to import enchant. I am using Win64.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the answer in this [GitHub page](https://github.com/rfk/pyenchant/issues/42).

In a nutshell, they have not shipped a wheel for the win_amd64 platform yet.

Comment: Is there a resolution to this? I am trying to use it on Windows 10 64 bit in Python 3.4.3.

Comment: One solution is to use 32 bit python 2.7 as mentioned in
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771227/install-pyenchant-on-a-windows-64-bit-machine (Indigo8's answer)

Comment: Is there a solution to this for Pydroid?  Trying to write on my mobile but its returning this error

Answer (score 24):

On Ubuntu, run `sudo apt-get install libenchant1c2a`

Comment: Didn't work. This did `sudo apt-get install python-enchant`

Comment: For search engines. Related answers are often what people are actually looking for. Seems like stack exchange is more for looking for general answers than a user-to-user  site

Answer (score 13):

Resolved: On Win7-64 I ran

pip3 install pyenchant==1.6.6

which seems to be the latest version of PyEnchant that still shipped with Win-64 binaries. Newer versions did not install for me, but this one did.

Answer (score 8):

For amazon ubuntu instance use.

```
yum install enchant
```

and then

```
pip install pyenchant
```

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't have yum.

Comment: for Ubuntu use ```sudo apt-get install enchant``` and then ```pip install pyenchant```

Answer (score 3):

For me, the problem I ran into was that I had an old version of pip. I installed the latest version and was able to download the pyenchant library.

`pip install -U pip`

Answer (score 2):

On Windows x64 I've solved this problem as follows:

- Click link https://pypi.org/project/pyenchant/#files and download pyenchant-2.0.0.win32.exe
- Launch it and while installing it using the installation wizard you must specify your python interpreter location which in my case is:

> C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe

Important:İf you use python32 interpreter you must specify this location:

> C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe

if you use python 3.5 interpreter version your location may be like this:

> C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe

and finish the installation. Pip commands will work now for other dependency packages.

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS, you can install it via `brew`:

```
brew install enchant
pip install pyenchant
```

Answer (score 1):

To run with docker on AWS:

1. With `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install enchant-2
```

2. With `apt`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y install enchant-2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have fix the bugs on the colab.

!apt update
!apt install enchant --fix-missing

After fixing the missing files, you could run the enchant.

Comment: while these instructions may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to resolve are as-

1. First check the operating system as below

```
import platform
os_type = platform.system()
print(f"Operating System Type: {os_type}")
```

2. If it is Linux, Then take sudo update and follow next steps, for other operating system follow this page https://pyenchant.github.io/pyenchant/install.html

```
!sudo apt-get update
```

3. Then check which libenchant version is in apt-cache

```
!apt-cache search libenchant
```

4. Insall libenchant accordingly

```
!sudo apt-get install libenchant{cached_version}
```