# Install pyenchant on a Windows 64-bit machine

Tags: python, windows, pyenchant

I want to install PyEnchant for spell checking and it requires [enchant](http://www.abisource.com/projects/enchant/) installed on my machine. But all the .exe files I could find were for win32 systems. Is there any other way to install it on Windows 64-bit machine?

Answer (score 7):

Currently there is no 64-bit version of Enchant.

PyEnchant can do your spelling check under Python 32 bit - if you have to use 64 bit Python then you will need to build Enchant and PyEnchant for 64 bit and resolve any issues yourself. This isn't trivial unfortunately.

Note that 32 bit Python works fine, for most usages, on 64 bit machines and in general more libraries are supported.

For installing on Python 2.7 (32 bit) all you should need to do is:

> pip install -U pyenchant

If you are having problems after this the next step is to uninstall and reinstall:

> pip uninstall pyenchant
>   pip install -U pyenchant

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have no choice but to use 64-bit for certain business reasons so I guess I just have to find another way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You could try checking this out, looks like someone was able to build a 64-bit version of Enchant but unfortunately his link (in the comments) is dead, perhaps the thread is helpful anyway: http://www.tolon.co.uk/2009/01/integrating-your-application-with-enchant-part-2/

Answer (score 2):

According to information here https://github.com/rfk/pyenchant enchant and pyenchant are no longer maintained. Sad.

People recommend another project instead: https://github.com/barrust/pyspellchecker

Comment: PyEnchant is still not maintained AFAIK, but while Enchant had a 7 year gap, it picked up in 2017 and still releasing in 2019... https://abiword.github.io/enchant/ https://github.com/AbiWord/enchant

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use PyEnchant for spell checking and suggestion, take a look at Pattern library, they support Python 3 on Windows 64-bit machine now. 
https://github.com/clips/pattern/tree/development

In case you are interested in usage:

```
from pattern.en import suggest
suggest("fianlly")
#output: [('finally', 1.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Going to leave this here for anyone who comes across it. There is a prebuilt 64-bit version of libenchant which is included in GIMP. By installing it and adding the libraries into your path, you can build pyenchant on a 64-bit version of Python.

First install GIMP: https://www.gimp.org/downloads/

From the CMD prompt either globally or within your Venv add the GIMP library location to your PATH

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin
```

Then install pyenchant

```
pip install pyenchant
```

Hope this helps.